# Азы вёрстки: Как правильно блок position: absolute; обернуть в ссылку?

Tags: html, css

Друзья смотрите есть такая ситуация:

```
<a href="#"><section id="thank">thank</section></a>
<a href="#"><section id="you">you</section></a>
<a href="#"><section id="bro">bro</section></a>
```

Всё кликабельно, работает и проходит валидацию, но дело в том что я считаю это не совсем врено и браузер мне об этом подсказывает: см.фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/q5MeE/

В **примере видим красные полоски в левом верхнем углу**, хотя по логике вещей красная полоса должна быть вокруг блока, что как бы говорит нам что "область ссылки" задана не совсем верно? Так как же сделать блок "кликабельным" без JS и скажем так "семантически верно"? Спасибо за внимание господа!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы для блоков section используете position: absolute, которое, во-первых, выносит данные блоки из обычного потока документа, а, во-вторых, в совокупности с top/right/bottom/keft позиционирует их относительно contained блока. Contained блоком служит ближайший родитель-элемент с position отличный от static т.е. relative, fixed и absolute. В вашей разметке т.к. таких не содержится, то его роль на себя берёт body.

Теперь о том как заставить работать ваш случай. С точки зрения HTML5 ( а судя по тому что вы используете section, речь идёт именно про этот стандарт ), тэг  может содержать внутри себя блочные элементы (чего нельзя в html4) и ваша разметка имеет право на существование, за исключением одного: а там точно нужен section? простым div'ом не обойтись?

Перенесите все правила по расположения, непосредственно на сами элементы ...,
например [так (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/q5MeE/2/).

HTML

```
<a  id="thank" href="#"><section>thank</section></a>
<a id="you" href="#"><section >you</section></a>
<a id="bro" href="#"><section >bro</section></a>
```

CSS

```css
#thank, 
#you,
#bro {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s 0s;
}

a { border: 2px solid red; }

section:hover { background: #333; color: #fff; }

#thank { left: 0px; bottom: 0px; }
#you { left: 50%; top: 50%; margin: -100px 0px 0px -100px; }
#bro { right: 0px; bottom: 0px; }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста! Успехов в вёрстке!

Answer (score -1):

очевидно, что абсолютное позиционирование блока section выкмдывает его за пределы тэга А.
топикстартер, у вас в голове реальная каша, перечитайте пожалуйста весьма полезный ресурс [учебник хтмл](http://htmlbook.ru)
особенно в раделе про позиционирование

Comment: Каша может быть и каша, про позиционирование я читал, но сути вопроса это не меняет: есть 3 блока, позиционированны абсолютно body, как сделать их "ссылками"?

Comment: умение принимать конструктивную критику и делать из нее правильные выводы - весьма важное качество для программиста.